# Creating a threaded timer in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, timer

Not sure if this is possible as I haven't found any answer to this on google. I have a trigger that activates after an insert, i want this trigger to start a timer that activates the mysql code inside after 5 seconds. I want if possible to have this be threaded so every other trigger(have more on same table) can be used at the same time, while this is counting down.

Is this possible? If not would it be possible to create a basic timer with just 5 seconds?

Note: I know it would be a lot easier(probably) written in php, but as i don't know php i wouldn't know how to go about this.

Comment: In your trigger just add `DO SLEEP(5)` or `SELECT SLEEP(5)`

Comment: @Daan wow, that seems extremely easy :P, but would the other trigger(s) still work while that one is sleeping?

Comment: Yes other triggers will still work.

Comment: @Daan Worked :) If you post it as answer i'll accept it. Could you help me with this aswell(not on this topic). When i use the sleep() they don't continue, what i mean is i want to delete from the table i enter the sql into. Basically i want to delete the row that i just made after 5 seconds. Is this at all possible?

Comment: It's so much easier when you ask about the problem you need to solve rather than ask why your solution is not working. There is unlikely to be any reason that you actually need to delete the row after 5 seconds - rather than being able to identify it as over 5 seconds old - but the former can be simulated simply with a view (assuming you can't simply change any SELECT to differentiate between rows newer or older than 5 seconds) combined with a periodic purge of expired data.